# How to check which permissions used by dependencies in flutter project?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-ios

I am working on the flutter application, where I have used several dependencies in my project as mentioned below:

```yaml
flutter_downloader: ^1.6.1 
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
font_awesome_flutter: ^8.4.0
fluttertoast: ^8.0.6
http: ^0.13.3
connectivity: ^0.4.3+2
flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
webview_flutter: ^2.0.0
url_launcher: ^6.0.4
flutter_html: ^0.10.2
flick_video_player: ^0.1.1
sizer: ^1.1.8
modal_bottom_sheet: ^1.0.0+1
advance_pdf_viewer: 2.0.0
share: ^2.0.4
package_info: ^2.0.0
image_picker: ^0.7.5
```

Now everything is working fine when I have uploaded the android release build on the play store, but when I am trying to publish the ios app on the app store I am getting the following response on the email that I am accessing location permission without mentioning purpose on info.plist file. Where I didn't use any location permission or location data on my app.

> ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist - Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data. Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't contain the APIs. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/protecting_the_user_s_privacy).

Now how can I check which dependency is using the location permission? So that I can mention the purpose of using the user's location on infp.plist file, or will take relevant actions with that dependency.

Comment: Can't you find ```NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription ``` in Info.plist and remove this key?

Comment: @NelsonThiago I don't want to add this permission to my application as there is no such feature related to user location. So here I basically want to remove this permission from my application. In that case, I have to find out which dependency is using this permission and have to find out the alternate solutions.

Comment: I know you don't want to, but it's demanding you to add it: ```all apps submitted to the App Store that access user data are required to include a purpose string```.